# how integrate facebook to iphone app

Tags: iphone, facebook, integration

I would like to show a *Like* button in my app, what is the latest way of doing this?

Answer (score -1):

Use the "LIKE" button code in an HTML document and load it into a `UIWebView`. Thats the easiest way.

Comment: Will this work with people's accounts that are already signed in with Facebook? What about users who are not signed onto Facebook on their iPhone web browser, because for example they use the Facebook iPhone app?

Comment: 1.) You can figure out a way to grab the session
2.) You can include a Facebook login option that you can save the session, or
3.) You can just let the user login, like most web-based Facebook apps

Comment: Only 2. and 3. will work. And considering that doing so in a UIWebView would require auth on every allocation of the UIWebView, that really isn't the easiest way.